What is the command "ContributionHierarchyQuery.QueryContributedHierarchy" doing in Azure DevOps?
We see quite high usage of the command "ContributionHierarchyQuery.QueryContributedHierarchy" in our Azure DevOps usage statistics which is contributing almost 10x as much to the TSTUs as the second command:

We found little documentation what this command does - same goes for ms.vss-build-web.ci-results-hub-route and Wiql.QueryByWiql - what is behind them?


What is the command "ContributionHierarchyQuery.QueryContributedHierarchy" doing in Azure DevOps?

This command contains data provider id and exactly this data provider gather data from DB and return it to user.
When you access the Azure DevOps Page, it will send the HierarchyQuery Post Request to get the data from DB. On server it is ContributionHierarchyQuery.QueryContributedHierarchy command with different contributionIds.
For example: When I access Pipeline page once, it will send more than 10 HierarchyQuery Post Requests.
We can check it in Browser Network trace tool:

In addition, other parts of Azure DevOps will also include these requests.
For ms.vss-build-web.ci-results-hub-route, it is more related to the Pipeline result page.
For Wiql.QueryByWiql, it is related to the Boards query feature and Dashboard work item widgets.
We can also get the similar records in the Browser Network traces.
If the number of certain instructions increases sharply in a short period of time and causes rate limit, we need to contact the Azure DevOps developer to check the specific operation information from the background.
